# HP Pavilion 15-E037cl boot failure after shutdown or hibernation

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion, cmos

When I shut down or hibernate my HP [Pavilion 15-E037cl](https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c03912086) [hardware manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03939658) system, it fails to boot. The power comes on, the wireless light turns on but the screen remains blank. Caps lock blinks periodically but it will not boot until I power down and up again. Sometimes I have to do that up to 5 times.

I changed the hard disk and added an extra 4 GB RAM to it, which brings it up to 8GB RAM, but no improvement.  It came with a 750 GB HDD, but changing to a 250 GB HDD using less power did not help.

I've just opened the entire system now, but cannot find the CMOS battery, or anything round that could probably be housing it.

Comment: I don't think that model has a CMOS battery, but rather a capacitor that acts like a battery, that is charged up. To test if its indeed the cmos battery, keep the laptop connected to power, turn it off, still keep it connected for as long as you need to to reproduce the problem, then power it back up. If the same happens as before, its not the CMOS battery.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did as you said and the same issue continued. To boot now, i have to power down a couple of times first

Comment: So you succesfully excluded that it is the battery. But it can be anything, even software. Have you reinstalled windows, or just cloned your disk when changing?

Comment: Have you performed the troubleshooting steps as outlined at https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-e000-notebook-pc-series/5355006/model/5444716/troubleshooting ? If so, please click [edit] above and to the left, and tell us which, specifically, adding that to your original post.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for replying so late. I took the system to an engineer and we were able to locate the cmos battery. Changed it and the issue still persists. I;ve reinstalled the windows twice on two separate hard disks. The last option that i'm to do now is update the system's bios

Comment: I also noticed that my laptop battery has refused to charge of recent. Noticed that today. The response is plugged in not charging. I restarted the system. Power offed it and rebooted. Removed and inserted the battery with and without the ac power cord being connected to light and still nothing. As a matter of fact, it has started to run down while connected to source. Any assistance on this will be appreciated.